# How to write Jasmine test cases for jQuery on() method

Tags: jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am new to Jasmine. Appreciate if someone can please brief me about how to write test cases for the following jquery code:

```
$(document).on('startViewDetail', function(event, transactionId) {
  $(document).trigger('ClearMessages', [{
    containerName: 'EnterDetails'
  }]);
  logger.debug('view transaction detail started');
  startViewTransaction(transactionId);
});

var startViewTransaction = function(transactionId){...}
```

Thanks in anticipation!

Jasmine test case for the above code:

```
describe('Working with transaction details component', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        spyOnEvent(document, 'startViewDetail');
        $(document).trigger('startViewDetail', mockDataObject.transactionId);
    });
    it('test startViewTransaction', function() {
        spyOn(document, 'startViewTransaction').and.callFake(function(e) {            console.log("This is a spy call for startViewTransaction");           });
        expect(document.startViewTransaction).toHaveBeenCalled();           expect(document.startViewTransaction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockDataObject.transactionId);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post has a broad scope so I'd start with one approach

So here are a few things you need to ask before you want to unit test your code

- Are you testing the functionality of your code or the functionality of the event binding
- If it is testing the event binding, then I'm afraid the jQuery has already thoroughly unit-tested it

I personally do not feel the need to test jQuery methods. That simply diverts the aim to test the actual hand-written code. Having said that here is a sample test I've prepared based on your code.

```
$(document).on('startViewDetail', function(event, transactionId) {
  $(document).trigger('ClearMessages', [{
    containerName: 'EnterDetails'
  }]);
  console.log('view transaction detail started');
  startViewTransaction(transactionId);
});

var startViewTransaction = function(transactionId) {
  console.log('started transaction with transactionId: ' + transactionId);
}

describe('sample test', function() {
  it('test startViewTransaction', function() {
    spyOn(window, 'startViewTransaction').and.callFake(function(e) {
      console.log("This is a spy call for startViewTransaction");
    });
    var obj = $(document);
    obj.trigger('startViewDetail', 1);
    expect(window.startViewTransaction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(window.startViewTransaction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
  })
});
```

EDIT:
Answering the comments:

- startViewDetail is not a method, it is an event name, so your line `spyOnEvent(document, 'startViewDetail');` is invalid. Remove it as it doesn't serve any purpose.
- I wonder why you are spying on the `document` object, the stray/stand-alone functions of javascript always go under window. So switch your spy to go against window rather than document.
- You should not use this line `$(document).trigger('startViewDetail', mockDataObject.transactionId);` in beforeEach, this should be used in your test like I used above.
- `spyOn(document, 'startViewTransaction').and.callFake(function(e) {            console.log("This is a spy call for startViewTransaction");           });` also needs modification, it should go against window object and NOT document.
- Same is the case with `expect(document.startViewTransaction).toHaveBeenCalled();           expect(document.startViewTransaction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockDataObject.transactionId);`

  - Jasmine [documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction) is the best source to understand how beforeEach, it, afterEach blocks work.

Comment: hey @Winter Soldier, I am seeing the following error:  Error: <spyOn> : startViewTransaction() method does not exist
    Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
Can you please let me know what is missing? Thanks!!

Comment: Can you please paste your code? Use your question, add a new EDIT section and paste your code without modifying your original question.

Comment: Updated my question with my test cases as per your inputs. Please check, thanks!